# Comparing array elements with each other

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a char array:

```
var charCode = [97,98,100,101,103];
```

I want to loop through this array and compare `charCode[i]` with `charCode[i+1]` so compare:

```
charCode[0] with charCode[1]
charCode[1] with charCode[2]
charCode[2] with charCode[3]
charCode[3] with charCode[4]
```

I also want to check if `charCode[i] +1 == charCode[i+1]` so this means i want to see if the next element is bigger than last by factor on one. One more thing, if e.g charCode[3] does not follow that rule I want to store the element's index in a separate variable.

```
function fearNotLetter(str) {
  var bool ;
  var charCode = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    charCode[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
    // charCode = [97,98,99,100,101,103]
  }
  for (var n = 0; n < charCode.length; n++) {
    /*
    here I'm comparing every element with every other element, 
    which is obviously not what I want
    */
    for (var j = n+1; j < charCode.length; j++) {
      if (charCode[n] + 1 < charCode[j]) {
        // don't know what to do here
      }
    }
  }
  return  charCode;
}
fearNotLetter("abcdeg");
```

Comment: you are doing a bit different thing in your code. You are iterating element n of the array against the remainder of the array i.e. (0 against 1,2,3,4,5....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array.reduce` and on mismatch, you can push that value to an intermediate array

```js
function fearNotLetter(str) {
  var charCode = [];
  str.split('').reduce(function(p,c){
    var code_p = p.charCodeAt()
    var code_c = c.charCodeAt()
    if(code_c-code_p !== 1)
      charCode.push(code_p)
    return c
  })  
  return  charCode;
}

console.log(fearNotLetter('abcdeg'))
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but this code returns  [98, 101] which is not what i wanted

Comment: since 103 -101 = 2, this means there is a value missing (102) after 101, so it should return 101

Comment: You are also missing `99` so even that should be highlighted. Right? so your final output will become: `[98, 101]`

Comment: so consider this array = [98,99,100,101,103] this one is missing 102. so I want to get the index number of the element after which 102 should come. sorry of the confusion

Comment: i'm getting an error: cant read property 'charCodeAt' of undefined

Comment: because your string is `undefined`. Check if you are doing it properly.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a normal loop, just don't go to the last item since you are checking `[i+1]`:

```js
var charCode = [97,98,100,101,103];
// Loop from 0 to n-2.
for (var i = 0; i < charCode.length - 1; i++) {
  if(charCode[i] +1 == charCode[i+1]) 
    console.log(charCode[i] +1 + '==' + charCode[i+1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a couple of modifications. You were running the inner loop where you did not need to.

```js
function fearNotLetter(str) {
  var bool ; // not sure what this is for
  // you can borrow map from array instead of looping
  var charCode = Array.prototype.map.call(str, str => str.charCodeAt(0))
  // loop over the characters. I am starting at 1 so we stop when we get to the end
  // you can access the first index by subtracting 1 from ii
  for (var ii = 1; ii < charCode.length; ii++) {
    if (charCode[ii - 1] === charCode[ii]) {
      console.log('samsies', ii - 1, char(charCode[ii]), char(charCode[ii]))
    }
    else if (charCode[ii-1] + 1 === charCode[ii]) {
      console.log('increment yo', ii - 1, char(charCode[ii -1]), char(charCode[ii]))
    }
  }
  return  charCode;
}
console.log(
  fearNotLetter("abcddeg")
)
// helper function
function char(code) {
  return String.fromCharCode(code)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to get the failed indexes?

```js
function fearNotLetter(str) {
 var failedElIndexes = [];
 var j = 0;
 for(var i = 0 in str){
  if(i < (str.length-1)){
   var n = str[i];
   var m = str[++i];
   if( String.fromCharCode(n.charCodeAt() + 1 ) != String.fromCharCode(m.charCodeAt() ) ) {
    console.log(i + ": " + str[i]);
    failedElIndexes[j] = i;
    j++;
   } 
  }else{
   break;
  }

 }
 return failedElIndexes;
}

var otherStr = "abcdeg";
var myErrIndexes = fearNotLetter(otherStr);
```